# Charboost unable to set campaign priorities in admin portal

Tags: chartboost

Recently I was trying to add and configure campaign and its priorities in Charboost admin portal. I created static and video interstitials and navigated to campaign priorities section, As expected, both static and video interstitials showed up. But if I select low to static and high to video placements, after screen reload, both placement priority automatically reset to highest.

It was working fine a month ago..

But recently I saw this bug in all browsers. ..

Comment: I do have the same exact issue...

Comment: there is no response from chartboost support also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got reply from Chartboost support. They are saying that they fixed this issue.

**mail from cb support**

> Good to hear from you again. Are you still seeing this today? Our
>   engineers had solved a similar problem yesterday (not exactly what
>   you're describing), though I'm wondering if you could've possibly been
>   affected by this.
>   Are you familiar with the chrome console? If so, could you please open
>   up the chrome console and click the network tab? With this open, go
>   ahead and try making the change (make sure to click save), and the
>   network tab will record the calls that are made or attempted to be
>   made. A screenshot of this would be incredibly helpful.
>
> I look forward to hearing from you and getting this resolved. Thanks
>   for the follow-up, and take care.